# Building modularized Java application targeting both Java 9 and older

Tags: java, java-platform-module-system

My application is working fine with Java 8 and older but fail to load classes that are not part of Java SE and fails with:

```
class MyClass (in unnamed module @0x4d14b6c2) cannot access class 
sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine (in module jdk.attach) because 
module jdk.attach does not export sun.tools.attach to unnamed module 
@0x4d14b6c2.
```

My original idea was to modularize my application and figure out if the classes I need have a public module to declare the dependency properly. However, as soon as I have declared dummy `module-info.java`, `javac` started to complain:

```
modules are not supported in -source 1.6; use -source 9 or higher to enable modules
```

EDIT: I am instructing maven-compiler-plugin to produce java 6 compatible bytecode as I need the application to support it. The actual arguments used are `-g -nowarn -target 1.6 -source 1.6 -encoding UTF-8`.

Perhaps I am missing something obvious but how do I build a jar that would work with Jigsaw as well as older java versions without it?

Comment: The answer is in the error: `use -source 9 or higher ` Though your question would need some more detail to be answered properly: what command you use to build it, what command you use to run it...

Comment: You're trying to build against an older JVM that doesn't support what you require. Use `-source 9` instead as the error suggests.

Comment: I have updated the question. I am tweaking the code to support java 9 without throwing out support for older java versions.

Answer (score 4):

With help from Jigsaw development mailing list, I managed to get the modularized codebase to build. (I ended up not needing the `HotSpotVirtualMachine` in particular).

- Compile `module-info.class` with `-source 9 -target 9` for the app to be runnable on older JVMs as those have no reason to load the class.
- The rest of the classes should be compiled with appropriate source/target level (Java 9 does not change anything here).

So two `javac` invocations are needed: by default only classes are compiled and module descriptors are skipped, if compiled using Java 9, module descriptors are compiled skipping all the regular classes.

---

Maven pom.xml declaration to keep the application *buildable* and *runnable* across different JDK versions is a bit clumsy but working:

```
    <!--
        When using compiler from java 8 and older, ignore module files altogether.
        Otherwise, use 2 phase compilation to build
          - all classes for target version and
          - module-info.java with 9+ source and target level
     -->
    <profiles>
      <profile>
      <id>jigsaw</id>
      <activation>
        <jdk>[1.9,)</jdk>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.9</source>
              <target>1.9</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>module-infos</id>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>compile</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <includes>
                    <include>**/module-info.java</include>
                  </includes>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <configuration>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>**/module-info.java</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```